when will hypersurfaces satisfy that $\mathcal{I}(\mathcal{Z}(f))=\langle f\rangle$
Let $k$ be a field that is not necessarily algebraic closed. Recall that a hypersurface in $\mathbb{A}^n$ is of the form $\mathcal{Z}(f)$ for some non-constant polynomial $f$.
I am confused about that when will we have that $\mathcal{I}(\mathcal{Z}(f))=\langle f\rangle$? It is well known that even $I$ is a radical ideal we still may have that $I\subset\mathcal{I}(\mathcal{Z}(I))$. For a explicit example, $\mathcal{Z}(x^2+1)=\varnothing$ if $k[\mathbb{A}^1]=\mathbb{R}[x]$, but $\langle x^2+1\rangle\subset\mathbb{R}[x]=\mathcal{I}(\mathcal{Z}(x^2+1))$.

As an easy consequence of Hilbert's Nullenstatz, we know that
$$\sqrt{I}=I(Z(I))$$ and so if $I$ is already radical we have
$$I=I(Z(I)).$$ But the Nullenstatz holds over algebraically closed fields, which we know $\mathbb{R}$ is not. In fact, your polynomial shows this as it has no real zero, and your example is used on the wiki page on the Nullenstatz.

Thanks! If $k$ is not algebraic closed, is there any useful method to judge whether $\mathcal{I}(\mathcal{Z}(f))=\langle f\rangle$? It spends me much time to show that the polynomials $xy-1,x^3-y^2,(x^2+y)(y-1)$ satisfy $\mathcal{I}(\mathcal{Z}(f))=\langle f\rangle$ by using Gröbner basis to obtain the uniqueness of remainder after general polynomial division.

@QuayChern mm, I don't really know of a general method for that, perhaps worth a seperate question? I'd be curious too.
